# Regular expression for domain validation in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I want to validate if only a domain is present in a string. For example the string "https://anyDomain" or "https://anyDomain/" should return true. Any other strings like "https://anyDomain/in" should return false.

The regex code that I have currently returns true for "https://anyDomain" but not for "https://anyDomain/". Below is the code:

```
var url = "https://anyDomain/";
var reg = /^https:\/\/[^\/]*$/;
console.log(reg.test(url));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following regex:

```
^https:\/\/.*.com(\/)?
```

Comment: Thank you.. Domain is not limited to .com... I just edited the question..

Comment: There are a lot of problems with this pattern. Better to use a more dedicated URI parser.